# scikit-learn cross_validate parameter n_jobs=-1 causes error

Tags: python, multithreading, scikit-learn

I use scikit-learn and the cross_validate function for a simple machine-learning model. I would like to set the functions parameter "n_jobs" to "-1" to allow to use of more than one core. However, if always get an error. Does anybody have a solution to this?

Here is the error message:

```
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 105, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 322, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 33, in __init__
    prep_data = spawn.get_preparation_data(process_obj._name)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 172, in get_preparation_data
    main_mod_name = getattr(main_module.__spec__, "name", None)

AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute '__spec__'
```

My code looks the following:

```
#Go trough each alpha, save average RMSE from crossvalidation into array
for k, i in enumerate(alpha):
    Model.set_params(Ridge__alpha = i)
    scores = cross_validate(Model,X,y,scoring='neg_mean_squared_error',cv=10,n_jobs=-1)
    avgRMSE[k] = np.mean(np.sqrt(-1*scores['test_score']))
```

I use the following versions:
Python 3.6
Anaconda 5.1
scikit-learn 0.19.1
scipy 1.0.0
numpy 1.14.2

The exact same script is running on my friends laptop (Win10 same OS as me) without any issues. I have no idea what the issue is here, so I really hope to get some help here :)

Answer (score 1):

IFF I execute my script in an external system terminal AND write

> if **name** == '**main**':

at the beginning of the script: My issue is solved.

Would still be wondering if there is a better solution, especially because on my friends system it is running without that fix (and he is using the same OS and hardware)

Example:

```
#Imports are here

if __name__ == '__main__':

    #All the other code start from here

    for k, i in enumerate(alpha):
        Model.set_params(Ridge__alpha = i)
        scores = cross_validate(Model,X,y,scoring='neg_mean_squared_error',cv=10,n_jobs=-1)
        avgRMSE[k] = np.mean(np.sqrt(-1*scores['test_score']))

    #More code
```

Comment: Had the same problem on windows and the same fix - this is a known issue with how parallel processing is implemented on windows. See the discussion here https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/5115